# How the performance will impact on mongodb if we make _id field string

Tags: mongodb

We are planing to change _id Field to string for document present in mongo db.

Please let me know what could possible impact in term of performance?

WE have expect DB size more then 4TB.

NOTE: uniqueness of _id will be handled by code.

Comment: It would be grate is  you Could you please elaborate more what  and why ?

Comment: All this sounds like a bad idea.

1. Why do you want to change the Id to string?
2. Enforce uniqueness by code, looks like you will have a lot of performance issues with this, if you do sharding or you want to scale your database, you are going to be in big trouble. So again, why do you want to do this to begin with?